# setup sudoers to mount network shares and loop devices and misc

Tags: security, mount, sudo

I would like to setup sudoers to grant users to mount all kind of network shares and loop devices to their home directory.

Here is a try that I found and changed a bit on one old post in unix.stackexchange.com:

```
Cmnd_Alias       MOUNTING = "/bin/mount -t nfs,smbfs,cifs  //* $HOME", "/bin/mount -o loop * $HOME", "/bin/umount $HOME"
Cmnd_Alias       SYSTEMDIAG = "/bin/dmesg"   # Yeah, I also would like to do this
%users           localhost = NOPASSWD: MOUNTING, SYSTEMDIAG
```

I would like to be sure this is fine before attempting it.

Answer (score 2):

**Line 1**: Mounts  Types: NetworkFileSystem, SambaFileSystems, and CommonInternetFileSystems on All Shared Paths to the Users Home Directory, Along with:
Mount All Devices as a loop, Along with
Unmounting, all Saved in the Array MOUNTING.

**Line 2**: Prints the kernel dump from the last successful boot, saved in the Array SYSTEMDIAG.

**Line 3**: If the User is logged in from a computer with the name localhost, he will not be asked for a password when executing commands in either Array.

Looks fine to me, unless your computer name is not localhost.  Make sure to use `visudo`